# How can I convert oracle XMLType to object in java?

Tags: xml, rest, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm developing a rest service using Spring MVC framework, using JPA for ORM. I have a field in oracle table which is of `XMLType`(very large size). How can I fetch it from DB using JPA and then convert it into object type(in order to later convert it to json object)? Is there any specific framework for that? I did read a few answers on using JAXB and implementing usertype interface in JPA. But could'nt find anything complete.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a documentation about [Java API to XMLType](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10790/xdb11jav.htm). It does not use JAXB, but a DOM API, with a JDBC for the connection to the database.

JAXB allows you to bind XML entities to Java objects. If you know the XML schema of an XML file, you can let generate a set of java classes. In order to use it, you must first extract an XML file from the database.